# How to detect when the user has scrolled to a certain area on the page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect page scroll to a certain point in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036850/how-to-detect-page-scroll-to-a-certain-point-in-jquery)
>   
>  [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scroling)

How can I detect when the user has reached this div:

```
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<div id="theTarget">I have been reached</div>
```

### EDIT

Got the answer from this question:

[Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scroling)

So I just did this:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function() {    
    if(isScrolledIntoView($('#theTarget')))
    {
        alert('visible');
    }    
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect page scroll to a certain point in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036850/how-to-detect-page-scroll-to-a-certain-point-in-jquery) and [Trigger events when the window is scrolled to certain positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672320/trigger-events-when-the-window-is-scrolled-to-certain-positions).

Comment: Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scroling

Comment: @ipr101 yeah that accepted answer does it.

Answer (score 61):

Compare the page scroll position to your element top position, than call your function.

**jQuery**

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#theTarget').position().top) {
    console.log('I have been reached');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="theTarget">I have been reached</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

**ES6 (Pure JS, no jQuery)**

```js
var target = document.querySelector('#theTarget');

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (window.scrollY >= target.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
    console.log('I have been reached');
  }
})
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="theTarget">I have been reached</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: This looks simpler than the solution I got from the other question so it would be better but I can't get it to work. For YourActionHere() I used a simple alert but they alert doesn't come up when I scroll to the target element.

Comment: In my example, I'm scrolling the entire document, is it your case? Maybe you're scrolling a part of the document, for example a Div. In this case, you need to replace $(document) by $(yourDiv).

Comment: I guess you would need to debounce the event since it fires like a gazillion times every second.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster you're right. A debounce would greatly help the performance.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can accomplish your goal by comparing values from your div position

```
var divPosition = $("#theTarget").offset().top;
```

and the window scroll position

```
var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a jquery appear plugin that I believe does exactly what you are asking.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/appear

```
$('#theTarget').appear(function() {
  $(this).text('Hello world');
});
```

It also ties into resize, and initial window size ... etc, etc, etc.