# Scroll past ID addClass to navigation menu to change currect class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a one page design website and would like to know how to add a class to my navigation menu items once I scroll past an ID.

I'm guessing it would be something like:

```
if at ID-X addClass .active to menuitem-y
```

In my navigation menu I have a link to prices (link is www.example.com/#prices). So when I click on Prices it smooth scrolls to the ID #prices.

So the could should look like:

```
if "#prices" addClass(.active)->Menuitem-y
```

I guess?

** Update **
Thanks to DaniP I've got some code that fires an alert when #prices is reached.

```
var target = $("#prices").offset().top;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target) {
        alert("made it!");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 250);
```

Can I put CSS instead of the alert? like `#menuitem-y{color:#000;}`

This works but only for one instance, what is the best way to apply this to more menu items?

```
var target = $("#prices").offset().top;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target) {
        $("#menu-item-16 a").addClass("active-prices");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 250);
```

Comment: Have you tried the Bootstrap scrollspy? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: I'm not using Bootstrap. I'm using http://materializecss.com. It has a scrollspy function. http://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html this will probably work the same. Ill have a go

Comment: Have you tried something ? at least search and try with your code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182342/how-to-detect-when-the-user-has-scrolled-to-a-certain-area-on-the-page-using-jqu

Comment: in your title, do you mean _current_ or _correct_ class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built a jquery plugin that sounds like it'd work for what you're doing here.

https://github.com/tferullo/eavesdrop

It adds a class to the navigation element as it corresponds to the element in view. Hope this helps!

Comment: Edit, sorry did not see the example folder! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks this script does do what I want. But now i have to implement it in my code.

I found an error in your script, in the files I downloaded it said:
`;function` at the beginning this should be `!function` according to your demo page...

Comment: glad it worked. The semi-colon before the function invocation is a safety net against concatenated scripts and/or other plugins which may not be closed properly.