# How can I time a script to run when a user has scrolled to a particular point on the page?

Tags: javascript, scroll, image, scrolltop

I have a picture which changes as the user scrolls down (see code below).

At the moment, it starts at the point scrolling begins, but I want it to only start changing when the user scrolls to a particular point (or pixel) on the page.

What do I need to add to the below to make this happen? Thank you in advance for your help and responses.

```
<div class='fauxcolumn-outer fauxcolumn-right-outer'>
<div style='position:relative'/>
<style>
        #photo { position: absolute; top:3px; right:29px; z-index:1 }
    </style>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'/>
    <script>
        var urls = [
            "http://abcd.jpg",
            "http://abcd.jpg",
            "http://abcd.jpg",
            "http://abcd.jpg",
            "http://abcd.jpg",
            "http://abcd.jpg",
            "http://abcd.jpg",
            "http://abcd.jpg",
            "http://abcd.jpg",
            "http://abcd.jpg"

        ];
        $(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
            var i = Math.min(Math.floor($(window).scrollTop()/50), urls.length-1)
                $("#photo img").attr("src", urls[i]);
            });
        });
    </script>
<body>
    <div id='photo'><img src='http://abcd.jpg'/>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: sounds like [jquery waypoint](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) will do exactly what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger events when the window is scrolled to certain positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672320/trigger-events-when-the-window-is-scrolled-to-certain-positions)

Comment: Thanks for the responses both of you. sounds like Waypoint is what I need, now I've just got to figure out how to add it to my code (as somebody with no experience in HTML / Java). TY for the help.