# Triggering css animate class on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, class, animation, scroll

I am using the animate.css classes on my page. 
Currently I have all animations built on hover function.

For example:

```
#folder:hover .middle-button{
            animation-name: slideRight;
            animation-duration: 1s; 
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     
            visibility: visible !important; 
        }
```

I would like to activate these animation classes on scroll and my question is:

What would be the easiest way to trigger this class using a Javascript function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger events when the window is scrolled to certain positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672320/trigger-events-when-the-window-is-scrolled-to-certain-positions)

Comment: I assume you want to add class when the element appears on the viewport?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. 
So I would like add a class when the element appears on the viewport. I have several div classes on the page that are using different animations. 

The animation for each div have been already added on the CSS sheet and I just need to understand how to trigger these animated classes if the element appears on viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I can do: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/ovDbk

It will add class `visible` to all the elements with className `onAppear`.

So, you can add class for all the elements that you want to animate on appear:

```
<div class="onAppear">This will be animated.</div>
```

And then on CSS (transition example, not animation - figure it out by yourself):

```
.onAppear {
  transition: transform 500ms;
}

.onAppear.visible {
  transform: translate3d(250px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, I got it to work now as you can see here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Afqza

Now the problem is that I would like only the handle class element to animate on viewport, now the whole SVG does the animation.
Any ideas how can I fix that?