# Animating SVG element on viewport

Tags: javascript, css, svg, jquery-animate, viewport

My question is related to my previous question [Triggering css animate class on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299777/triggering-css-animate-class-on-scroll/25302717)

I am trying to figure out how to trigger the viewport Javascript on the inner SVG element class.
You can see here the example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Afqza

```
<div style="height: 400px;"></div>
<svg version="1.1" id="lock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="85px" height="85px" viewBox="0 0 103 103" ><g><g><g><g><circle style="fill:#E84849;" cx="51.5" cy="51.501" r="51.125"/></g></g></g></g><g><g><g class="shackle"><path style="fill:#CFC7BE;" d="M78.345,46.518c0-14.869-11.813-28.387-26.386-28.387c-14.573,0-26.386,13.518-26.386,28.387h6.829c0-11.021,8.756-21.419,19.557-21.419s19.557,10.398,19.557,21.419H78.345z"/><path style="fill:#E8E7E7;" d="M61.385,20.101v7.816c3.039,1.927,5.583,4.717,7.362,7.975V24.879C66.562,22.886,64.076,21.26,61.385,20.101z"/></g><g><path style="fill:#F4E028;" d="M78.358,79.801c0,3.116-2.579,5.642-5.765,5.642H31.281c-3.186,0-5.764-2.525-5.764-5.642V46.419c0-3.116,52.841-3.116,52.841,0V79.801z"/></g><g><path style="fill:#DAC425;" d="M58.047,59.944c0-3.253-2.638-5.89-5.889-5.89c-3.253,0-5.889,2.637-5.889,5.89c0,2.481,1.536,4.599,3.705,5.468v5.431c0,1.151,0.935,2.084,2.085,2.084c1.153,0,2.086-0.933,2.086-2.084v-5.36C56.418,64.666,58.047,62.498,58.047,59.944z"/></g><g><path style="fill:#D0B82B;" d="M46.048,59.944c0-3.253,2.637-5.89,5.891-5.89c0,0-4.105,2.737-4.105,5.99c0,3.312,3.097,5.276,3.097,5.276v5.581c0,1.153,1.104,2.024,1.104,2.024c-1.15,0-2.085-0.933-2.085-2.084v-5.36C47.677,64.666,46.048,62.498,46.048,59.944z"/></g></g><g><polygon style="fill:#F8E349;" points="68.747,85.442 61.385,85.442 61.385,44.219 68.747,44.585 "/></g></g></svg>


    .shackle {

     animation-name: open;
    -webkit-animation-name: open;   
    animation-duration: 0.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin: bottom left;

}

@keyframes open {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);    
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);    
    }                       
}

@-webkit-keyframes open {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);    
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);    
    }

}

var onAppear = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  onAppear = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("#lock"), function(item ) {
    return item;
  });
}, false);

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  onAppear.forEach(function(elem) {
    var vwTop = window.pageYOffset;
    var vwBottom = (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight);
    var elemTop = elem.offsetTop;
    var elemHeight = elem.offsetHeight;

    if (vwBottom > elemTop && ((vwTop - elemHeight) < elemTop)) {
     elem.classList.add("shackle");
    } else {
      elem.classList.remove("shackle");
    }
  });
}, false);
```

Currently the whole padlock animates instead of the shackle that I want to animate. 
Must be something simple but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: you are adding the 'shackle' class to the `svg` you need to add it to the `svg` element with class `handle`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I had a wrong class name there. However, that does not solve the problem. The shackle element does still not animate.

Comment: can you update your codepen with your updated code please :)

Comment: Thanks, the codepen is updated as well=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you arent applying the animation class to the shackle element, you are applying it to the `lock` element.

Because you are playing around with CSS3 and SVG, I can assume you dont need to accommodate for IE7 and below. Therefore, we can assume it's safe to use JS's `querySelector` method.

1. First, we'll update the style definition to indicate the class is for an animation definition (and also to separate it from the class on the shackle element that we'll use to select it).

   **change .shackle to .animShackle in CSS**
2. Second, we'll need to update the scroll event listener to search within the supplied element for the `.shackle` classed element, and then apply the animation class to that.

   **update JS**

JS

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  onAppear.forEach(function(elem) {
    var vwTop = window.pageYOffset;
    var vwBottom = (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight);
    var elemTop = elem.offsetTop;
    var elemHeight = elem.offsetHeight;
    var shackle = elem.querySelector('.shackle');

    if (vwBottom > elemTop && ((vwTop - elemHeight) < elemTop)) {
     shackle.classList.add("animShackle");
    } else {
      shackle.classList.remove("animShackle");
    }
  });
}, false);
```

---

**UPDATE**

To make the code more extensible to the need for additional elements with their own animations we need to change some of our variable names so that they feel more universal, and update the way we are getting and setting the animation class.

1. Add a universal class to the animated SVG's so that we can find them in our onAppear function

   **add class `animatedSVG`**
   **update `querySelectorAll` method to use new class rather than single `id`**
2. Update the class name on the animated element within the SVG so that we can access it within the scroll `onAppear.forEach` method

   **update class `.shackle` to `.animatedElement` in HTML**
   **update `elem.querySelector` method to use new class rather than non-generic `.shackle`**
3. Use the SVG's `id` attribute to create a classname for animation

   **add a new variable called `animationClass` made from the SVG `id` with 'anim' prepended**

HTML now requires the following 3 things:

1. `id` attribute on SVG
2. `class="animatedSVG"` on SVG
3. `class="animatedElement"` on element within SVG you wish to animate

Updated JS

```
var onAppear = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  onAppear = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".animatedSVG"), function(item) {
    return item;
  });
}, false);

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  onAppear.forEach(function(elem) {
    var vwTop = window.pageYOffset;
    var vwBottom = (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight);
    var elemTop = elem.offsetTop;
    var elemHeight = elem.offsetHeight;
    var animatedElem = elem.querySelector('.animatedElement');
    var animationClass = 'anim'+elem.id;

    if (vwBottom > elemTop && ((vwTop - elemHeight) < elemTop)) {
     animatedElem.classList.add(animationClass);
    } else {
      animatedElem.classList.remove(animationClass);
    }
  });
}, false);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpkDC)

Comment: Thanks, this works! One more question, if I have several SVGs with different animation classes? How would I modify the JS code. E.g. SVG Id "Clock" with class "pointer".